# C# screen scraping processing a login control using POST

Tags: screen-scraping

I am trying to login to a website using screen scraping and I am having difficulties.

```
 private static string GetWebRequestContent(Uri uri)
    {
        string sid = String.Empty;

        string userName = "username";
        string password = "password";
        string postData = string.Format("FormName=Login&Login={0}&Password={1}&FormAction=login&ret_page=%2FDefault.asp&querystring=",userName,password);
        byte[] postBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(postData);


        HttpWebRequest req = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(uri);
        req.UserAgent = "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 6.0; WOW64; SLCC1; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.0.30729; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; InfoPath.2; .NET4.0C; .NET4.0E; MS-RTC LM 8)";
        req.KeepAlive = false;
        req.Proxy = new WebProxy(IPAddress,PORT);
        req.Method = "POST";
        req.Host = host;
        req.Referer = referer;
        req.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
        req.ContentLength = postBytes.Length;

        StreamWriter requestwriter = new StreamWriter(req.GetRequestStream(), System.Text.Encoding.ASCII);
        requestwriter.Write(postData);
        requestwriter.Close();

        try
        {
            using (HttpWebResponse res = (HttpWebResponse)req.GetResponse())
            {
                using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(res.GetResponseStream()))
                {
                    sid = sr.ReadToEnd().Trim();
                }
            }
        }
        catch (WebException e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(uri.ToString());
            Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
        }

        return sid;
    }
```

All that I get back is the login form, it is never logging me in.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Try monitoring what request is sent in your browser and then replicate this in your script. There are various firefox extensions that will help you do this, such as [TamperData](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/tamper-data/), [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/), and [LiveHttp](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/live-http-headers/).